# python class to be used everywhere

Tags: python, class

I have some dictionaries in python with headers similar to this one:

```
HEADERS['companies-details'] = ["company_id","company_url","company_name",
"free_places","accepted_perc","domain_raw",
"domain_cleaned","email","email_domain","phone_main","phone_main_cleaned",
"founded_year","employee_count","employee_count_cleaned","employee_count_cat",
"revenue","industry_raw","industry_cat","industry_cat_prob","address_raw",
"address_street","postal_code","city","date" ];
```

When I write a CSV from the dictionary, I use this header.

When I create the SQL table, I have to write all the fields in the header:

```
" create table job.companies ("
" company_id varchar(128),"
" company_name varchar(128),"
" company_url varchar(512),"
" free_places int,"
" accepted_perc int,"
" domain_raw varchar(256),"
" domain_cleaned varchar(256),"
" email_main varchar(256),"
" email_domain varchar(128),"
" phone_main_raw varchar(256),"
" phone_main_cleaned varchar(64),"
" founded_year int,"
" employee_count_raw varchar(256),"
" employee_count_cleaned int,"
" employee_count_cat varchar(32),"
" revenue varchar(128),"
" industry_raw varchar(256),"
" industry_cat varchar(256),"
" industry_cat_prob float,"
" address_raw   varchar(256),"
" address_street varchar(128),"
" postal_code int,"
" city varchar(256),"
" date_scraped timestamp,"
" PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`) )"
```

When I write them to SQL, I have to write again all the fields checking for exact matching, if some mistakes, no flexibility:

```
add_company = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO companies "
"( company_id , company_name , company_url , free_places , accepted_perc , 
domain_raw , domain_cleaned , email_main , email_domain , phone_main_raw, "
" phone_main_cleaned , founded_year , employee_count_raw , employee_count_cleaned 
, employee_count_cat , revenue , industry_raw , industry_cat , "
" industry_cat_prob , address_raw  , address_street , postal_code , city , 
date_scraped )"
"VALUES (%(company_id)s, %(company_name)s, %(company_url)s, %(free_places)s, % 
(accepted_perc)s, %(domain_raw)s, %(domain_cleaned)s, %(email_main)s,"
"%(email_domain)s, %(phone_main_raw)s, %(phone_main_cleaned)s, %(founded_year)s, 
%(employee_count_raw)s, %(employee_count_cleaned)s, %(employee_count_cat)s,"
"%(revenue)s, %(industry_raw)s, %(industry_cat)s, %(industry_cat_prob)s, % 
(address_raw)s, %(address_street)s, %(postal_code)s, %(city)s, %(date_scraped)s)"
)
```

When I get the data from the source, I have to init all the fields before beginning, because, if some field missing, then will provoke an error in csv writing or MySQL insert

```
out['company_id'] = cid; out['company_url'] = link;
out['free_places'] = ""; out['accepted_perc'] = "";
out['industry_raw'] = ""; out['industry_cat'] = ""; out['industry_cat_prob'] = 
"";out["employee_count_raw"] = "";  out["employee_count_cleaned"] = ""; 
out["employee_count_cat"] = "";out["domain_raw"] = ""; out["domain_cleaned"] = "";
out["founded_year"]=""; out['revenue'] = ""  ;out["job_title"] = ""; 
out['phone_main_raw'] = ""; out['phone_main_cleaned'] = "";
out['address_raw'] = ""; out['address_street'] = ""; out['postal_code'] = ""; 
out['city'] = "";out['email_main'] = ""; out['email_domain'] = "";
out["first_name"] = ""; out["middle_name"] = ""; out["last_name"] = "";
```

What's the way to write all this with a class?
I never dedicated to classes, I never like those, because I've been always working with 2/3 fields array, but in this case, I think they could be useful.

When I add or remove a field, I have to remember to change in 4/5 code sections. And, since I'm writing code for a dozen of dictionaries like this, it gets complicate to match all the correct fields

Is there a way to create a class "company", and then get back the string when I write:

```
-the csv header <- return a list, 
-the table creation <- return a predefined str - I think with __str__, 
-the table insert, <- same as before, but 2 different __str__
-the table select, <- same as before, but different __str__
-the init and fulfill during the data acquisition? <- I think during the __init__
```

in the different needed formats?

thx

**---- EDIT ----**

I'm looking at pydantic --> Basemodel and typing -> Optional
I don't know if I'm on the right direction

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional

class CompanyDetail(BaseModel):
    company_id: str
    company_url: str
    company_name : str
    free_places: Optional[str]
    accepted_perc: Optional[str]
    domain_raw: Optional[str]
    domain_cleaned: Optional[str]
    email_main: Optional[str]
    email_domain: Optional[str]
    phone_main_raw: Optional[str]
    phone_main_cleaned: Optional[str]
    founded_year: Optional[str]
    employee_count_raw: Optional[str]
    employee_count_cleaned: Optional[str]
    employee_count_cat: Optional[str]
    revenue: Optional[str]
    industry_raw: Optional[str]
    industry_cat: Optional[str]
    industry_cat_prob: Optional[float]
    address_raw: Optional[str]
    address_street: Optional[str]
    postal_code: Optional[str]
    city: Optional[str]
    date_scraped: Optional[str]
```

and

```
return CompanyDetail(**out);
```

and now I will see how to write the object in the needed format, case by case.

Comment: The solution is, clearly, to create a class for this. Whether it is vanilla class, a pydantic model, a dataclass, a namedtuple or something else depends on how you feel about it and it's quite opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share the way I solved:

First, I created those objects, like this one.
pyndatic automatically parse value and can be used also to evaluate correctness of data, if needed

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List,Optional

class CompanyDetail(BaseModel):
    company_id: str
    company_url: str
    company_name : str
    free_places: Optional[str]
    accepted_perc: Optional[str]
    domain_raw: Optional[str]
    domain_cleaned: Optional[str]
    email_main: Optional[str]
    email_domain: Optional[str]
    phone_main_raw: Optional[str]
    phone_main_cleaned: Optional[str]
    founded_year: Optional[str]
    employee_count_raw: Optional[str]
    employee_count_cleaned: Optional[str]
    employee_count_cat: Optional[str]
    revenue: Optional[str]
    industry_raw: Optional[str]
    industry_cat: Optional[str]
    industry_cat_prob: Optional[float]
    address_raw: Optional[str]
    address_street: Optional[str]
    postal_code: Optional[str]
    city: Optional[str]
    date_scraped: Optional[str]
```

The dictionary output, I convert in pyndatic type like this, because all the fields are the same

```
newCompanyEl = CompanyDetail(**out);
```

In the CSV creation, I had a input of array of new types

```
def csvCreate(arr, f):
    file = open(f, 'w', newline ='', encoding="utf8") 
    with file: 
        # identifying header   
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = arr[0].dict().keys(), quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        # write data row-wise into the csv file 
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in arr:
            writer.writerow(row.dict())
```

In mysqlconnector, with their syntax, I used this:

```
import mysql.connector

#### fields are just all the dict keys joined with a ','
fields = ", ".join(company.dict().keys());

### values in the form of %(field1)s, %(field2)s
values = "%("+")s, %(".join(company.dict().keys())+")s";

add_company = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO company ("+str(fields)+") VALUES ("+values+")")

cursor.execute(add_company, company.dict());
```

same in the table creation, just use their specific format

everything work as expected
and now if I add or remove a field,
I have just to alter the table on the DB.